# Python multi threads synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

I created several threads to run the same function with different arguments concurrently. I want each thread to be blocked until a delay passed from the run of the last thread. I use `threading.Queue` to read and write the results of threads. To be specific, the function sends an HTTP request to a server. I want my program to wait for example 5 seconds after each sending a request.

```
        for fake in fake_users:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_wrapper, args=(args1, args2, q))
            thread.start()
        while users:
            result = q.get()
            ....
```

The body of the function is:

```
        while True:
            headers = get_api_headers()
            
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, verify=cert_file,
                                    allow_redirects=False)
            response.raise_for_status()
            if response.status_code == 200:
                html = response.text
            .....
```

A URL is monitored through five threads with different arguments. To do this, each time a GET request is sent to the server. This runs in a `while` loop. I want to ensure that each request is sent after 5 seconds passed from the last request.

- I can define a global `threading.Lock()` to lock sending the GET request something like this:

```
with lock:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This approach only prevents sending requests at the same time, but I want 5 seconds delay between each sending request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
for i,fake in enuemrate(fake_users):
    delay = 5 * i
    thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_wrapper, args=(args1, args2, q, delay))
    thread.start()
```

and add a **`time.sleep(delay)`** statement at the beginning of your function?

Comment: The function runs forever in an infinite `while` loop.

Comment: @MatinMoezi You have to mention such details. Please edit your post and share the code of your function then.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using `threading.Condition` ([this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition)). Each thread waits for a condition callable using `wait_for()` and `notify()`, which is called from another thread.

```
def worker(arg):
    while True:
        with cv:
            cv.wait_for(cond)
            print(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} worker {arg} started.")

            # Send GET request to the server

            print(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')} worker {arg} finished.")
            cv.notify()


def cond():
    time.sleep(5)
    return True

cv = threading.Condition()
for i in range(5):
    thrd = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    thrd.start()
```